# Match range to closest of 1 of 3 variables

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

consider the following sheet

```
ID Hours
1  16
2  24
3  50
4  36
```

now I need to match the values in Col B to one of 3 variables

16, 25, 30

so what I'm trying to do is match the number in B2:B to the closest number of the above three variables... not able to work this out with `=match`... can anyone help?

adding a sheet for clarity:

Basically, what I want to do is assign a variable to a store based on their hours. so if ID 3 is 50 then they will be assigned the variable of 30 and have 20 left over, so essentially they have will two variables, one of 30 one of 16 with a remainder of 4. I've done this now with a few if/match statements but I was wondering if there was a one formula method to match one variable to another.

sheet: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10x2-5DnCUFuFDMKLO4EYgCXV2rl2LKfAHLerqj36DH4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: what could be the maximum base hour? 100? more?

Comment: also, you want all results in one column?

Comment: it could be anything from 12 to 150 its based on a sales forecast. More than one column is fine if we are observing one observation per cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case you want to round it between 3 numbers on a linear plane use nested **`IF`** like:

```
=IF(    B2 <  20.5 ; 16;
 IF(AND(B2 >= 20.5 ;
        B2 <  27.5); 25;
 IF(    B2 >= 27.5 ; 30; )))
```

which divides plain into:

```
             16        25    30
-∞ __________|_________|_____|___________ ∞ +
                  |       |
                 20.5    27.5
```

[image]

---

## UPDATE:

basically, all you need is this simple formula pasted in **C2** and dragged down - 
(it can devide inputs from **B** column up to **360h**):

> **`=SPLIT(IF(AND(B2>=16;B2<25);16;IF(AND(B2>=25;B2<30);25;IF(B2>=30;30;)))&" |"& IF(SUM(B2-30)>=16;IF(SUM(B2-30)<25;16;IF(AND(SUM(B2-30)>=25;SUM(B2-30)<30);25;IF(SUM(B2-30)>=30;30;)))&"|";IF(SUM(B2-30)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-30)=0;;SUM(B2-30));IF(SUM(B2-25)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-25)=0;;SUM(B2-25));IF(SUM(B2-16)>0;SUM(B2-16);))))& IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*2))>=16;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*2))<25;16;IF(AND(SUM(B2-SUM(30*2))>=25;SUM(B2-SUM(30*2))<30);25;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*2))>=30;30;)))&"|";IF(SUM(B2-30-30)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-30-30)=0;;SUM(B2-30-30));IF(SUM(B2-30-25)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-30-25)=0;;SUM(B2-30-25));IF(SUM(B2-30-16)>0;SUM(B2-30-16);))))& IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*3))>=16;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*3))<25;16;IF(AND(SUM(B2-SUM(30*3))>=25;SUM(B2-SUM(30*3))<30);25;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*3))>=30;30;)))&"|";IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*2)-30)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*2)-30)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*2)-30));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*2)-25)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*2)-25)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*2)-25));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*2)-16)>0;SUM(B2-SUM(30*2)-16);))))& IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*4))>=16;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*4))<25;16;IF(AND(SUM(B2-SUM(30*4))>=25;SUM(B2-SUM(30*4))<30);25;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*4))>=30;30;)))&"|";IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*3)-30)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*3)-30)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*3)-30));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*3)-25)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*3)-25)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*3)-25));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*3)-16)>0;SUM(B2-SUM(30*3)-16);))))& IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*5))>=16;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*5))<25;16;IF(AND(SUM(B2-SUM(30*5))>=25;SUM(B2-SUM(30*5))<30);25;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*5))>=30;30;)))&"|";IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*4)-30)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*4)-30)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*4)-30));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*4)-25)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*4)-25)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*4)-25));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*4)-16)>0;SUM(B2-SUM(30*4)-16);))))& IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*6))>=16;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*6))<25;16;IF(AND(SUM(B2-SUM(30*6))>=25;SUM(B2-SUM(30*6))<30);25;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*6))>=30;30;)))&"|";IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*5)-30)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*5)-30)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*5)-30));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*5)-25)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*5)-25)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*5)-25));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*5)-16)>0;SUM(B2-SUM(30*5)-16);))))& IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*7))>=16;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*7))<25;16;IF(AND(SUM(B2-SUM(30*7))>=25;SUM(B2-SUM(30*7))<30);25;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*7))>=30;30;)))&"|";IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*6)-30)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*6)-30)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*6)-30));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*6)-25)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*6)-25)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*6)-25));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*6)-16)>0;SUM(B2-SUM(30*6)-16);))))& IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*8))>=16;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*8))<25;16;IF(AND(SUM(B2-SUM(30*8))>=25;SUM(B2-SUM(30*8))<30);25;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*8))>=30;30;)))&"|";IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*7)-30)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*7)-30)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*7)-30));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*7)-25)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*7)-25)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*7)-25));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*7)-16)>0;SUM(B2-SUM(30*7)-16);))))& IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*9))>=16;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*9))<25;16;IF(AND(SUM(B2-SUM(30*9))>=25;SUM(B2-SUM(30*9))<30);25;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*9))>=30;30;)))&"|";IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*8)-30)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*8)-30)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*8)-30));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*8)-25)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*8)-25)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*8)-25));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*8)-16)>0;SUM(B2-SUM(30*8)-16);))))& IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*10))>=16;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*10))<25;16;IF(AND(SUM(B2-SUM(30*10))>=25;SUM(B2-SUM(30*10))<30);25;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*10))>=30;30;)))&"|";IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*9)-30)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*9)-30)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*9)-30));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*9)-25)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*9)-25)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*9)-25));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*9)-16)>0;SUM(B2-SUM(30*9)-16);))))& IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*11))>=16;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*11))<25;16;IF(AND(SUM(B2-SUM(30*11))>=25;SUM(B2-SUM(30*11))<30);25;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*11))>=30;30;)))&"|";IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*10)-30)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*10)-30)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*10)-30));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*10)-25)>=0;IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*10)-25)=0;;SUM(B2-SUM(30*10)-25));IF(SUM(B2-SUM(30*10)-16)>0;SUM(B2-SUM(30*10)-16);))));"|")`**

### **demo spreadsheet: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R7pv3xVHYgGFfk-7e2eVkhD8IiNyvO1fOlK_Q7g3OMg/edit#gid=0)**

[image]

Comment: That is the longest excel formula I have ever seen! Thank you!

Comment: One final comment if I wanted to change the variables to a cell reference would that work with this formula?

Comment: @Datanovice yup, I don't see a reason why it would not

Comment: Thanks again! does the "|" represent an OR statement here? I'm trying to reproduce your code by having one variable and a max hour of 30

Comment: @Datanovice no, "|" is separator symbol > a|b|c will be separated into 3 cells (each letter in one cell) while "|" will be omitted

Comment: I see, I've not been able to reproduce this, I basically get lost when you start to sum * and I can't tell where the code changes would you mind explaining? I want to able to re-create this from scratch as it will be so useful for me in my current role!=SPLIT(IF(AND(B2>=16,B2<25),16,IF(AND(B2>=25,B2<30),25,IF(B2>=30,30,)))&" |")

Comment: @Datanovice hmm... this should help: https://i.imgur.com/Bh7ik7I.png & https://i.imgur.com/KldPeJx.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83042/discussion-between-datanovice-and-user0).